# Which episode did Rukawa explain why he wanted to join Shohoku?

Tags: slam-dunk

Anybody remembers in which episode did Rukawa explained the reason that he wanted to join Shohoku was simply because - it's closer to his house!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was during Shohoku vs Ryonan which happened in Episode 67 during the last 7 minutes